# How to have a Text Area in my Web application?

Tags: java, html

I want to make a blog page in my web application. I want to have a **large text area to enter atleast 300 words in my blog page.** it should have **spell check**. **making bold option**. It should be like the s**ame window in StackOverFlow where am entering my question now**.

How to achieve this. Any suggestions Please?

Comment: @all Thanks a lot. everyone are awesome. I am confused which i should use? Super suggestion thanks a lot.

Comment: first you have to choose if you want a markdown or a wysiwyg editor. Stackoverflow uses a markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the one used by Stackoverflow:

http://wmd-editor.com/

Comment: i implemented it but the problem is the wmd link and logo is in the button bar after all the options in the end. How to remove that?

Comment: I don't know if it is permitted but you can delete few lines in wmd-base.js (see line 1140)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few WSIWYG editors out there.  The one probably most-used is [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Personally, I prefer the [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

Comment: After having worked with joomla, I came to the conclusion that I dislikes TinyMCE, because of the terrible code it produces.

Comment: @Jannis, that's why I prefer YUI's.  :-D  I have seen implementations of TinyMCE where much of the toolbar is stripped down, and then it isn't so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It is one of the best free editors i know of.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout mootools version of WSIWYG editor.  It is very lightweight and simple.  http://cheeaun.github.com/mooeditable/  build from javascript framework Mootools